# Ex-employees have my source code and client database. What can I do?

Tags: software-industry, law, russia

I am an author of an open-source project which is pretty popular within some industry. Also I am a founder of a company which contributes to the project and provides paid support for it.

We had a public version of our product, let's say v1, and a private version v2 that was under development. Some time ago all my employees left me, founded a new company and forked my public repo. They continued to develop their fork, and I am actually fine with it. The thing that I'm not fine with, is that they have the source code of the private version v2 and the database of my company clients.

To make things even worse, there hadn't been any public activity on the v1 project for some time, and finally I've recently found out that my former employees had used my client database to contact my clients offering them support services and stating something like 'the old project is dead, welcome the new one with the whole former team'.

What can I do in this situation?

How can I prevent my former employees from using the old private code?

Should I contact my clients and describe the situation? What should I tell them?

The only thing I can think of is to give my clients an early access to the private version v2 before my former employees do it.

Comment: And you let these guys go without signing anything to protect your IP?

Comment: I suggest you focus solely on how to handle this with your clients (although why can't you just explain the situation? What problem do you foresee with that?). Dealing with the legal aspect of them stealing your code [requires a lawyer](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2694).

Comment: You might also want to reflect on why **all** your employees could've thought creating a new company doing the same thing, but without you, was a good idea. Unless they're just really terrible people, reflecting will probably reveal some things it would be good for you to improve on.

Comment: Talk to a lawyer ASAP. We might be able to cover parts of this question but you need reliable legal advice first.

Comment: They stole your code and your client list and created a new company that is pushing your company out. You need a lawyer as this is almost certainly illegal and you should be able to get damages awarded for the damage they did to your company. You need a lawyer before talking to any of the clients as there are likely things they would want you to say or not say.

Answer (score 9):

Take whatever papers that these guys signed on departure and go buy some lawyer time.

This is all you can do at this stage.  If you didn't adequately protect your v2 IP, then you're kind of stuck.

If you have protection, you have something to fight them with.

Answer (score 3):

This is one for the lawyers I'm afraid, I'm really hoping you had them sign something at some point that protected your IP (Most employment contracts will have some sort of provision to that effect) as without something legally binding and signed you will get into essentially a he-said/she-said argument and you're going to struggle to get anything done to prevent them continuing.

Contacting your clients (whether you have an early-access option or not) is a good idea though, if you can explain the situation without being too inflammatory about your former employees (I appreciate that will be easier said than done given the anger you must be feeling) then you may stand a chance of getting them onside and retaining them. After all entering into business relationships with a group that has already proven themselves to be less than trustworthy doesn't make good business sense. It will also give you the opportunity to get out ahead of any messaging they may do to your clients putting forward their version of events because if they took your code you can bet your bottom dollar they took your client list too!

Comment: Even without an explicit agreement, copyright in works made for hire may belong to the employer. For the US, see [Copyright Ownership and Transfer](https://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap2.html). Still seems like a case for getting a lawyer.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan is absolutely right on this one.  The IP laws are VERY different between employees and contractors.  I hope you had them as W-2 employees.  Go get a **GOOD** lawyer, and get them to issue a "Cease and Desist" letter immediately, and ask about a permanent court order.  You need someone with a bar card and experience in business / IP law.  Then you need to look at your PR, and get your messaging in front of your clients.  Finally, figure out how your employee relations went so badly.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan The question is tagged "Russia". I'm not sure whether their laws are very similar to the ones in the US.

Comment: @Abigail True - that is why the employer should consult a lawyer.